# mongoDb $in with aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I write an `$in` query along with aggregate in mongoDB? I want to write an equivalent mongoDB query for the SQL below

```
SELECT name,count(something) from collection1
where name in (<<list of Array>>) and cond1 = 'false'
group by name
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The equivalent mongo query follows:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "name": { "$in": arrayList },
        "cond1": "false"
    } }, 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$name",
        "count": { "$sum": "$something" }
    } }
])
```

Comment: What works for me is name: { "$in": arrayList } (and not "name")

Comment: Hi, question... How can I send "$in": <all>, if I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have an Schema with field tags

```
{
 tags: ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
}
```

and you want find out apple inside tags with aggregate function then

```
const keywords = "apple"; // req.body.keywords

const filter =  { $match : { tags: {$in : [keywords] } }}

Schema.aggregate(filter).then(result=>{
 // You can do what you want with result
})
```

Comment: from MongdoDB: $in operator matches values in array as long as at least one element matches -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/