# MongoDB query and Java code with Java aggregation driver

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can Some one help me telling if the below query for multiple accounts is correct or not so that I can fetch the sum of "mt" for multiple accounts in one go from my collection?

I have tried the query as below,

```
    db.getCollection('XYZ').aggregate([
            {$match: {
                $and:[{
                    $or: [
                        {"try.Ind":"A","_id.a":"BB","_id.b":"HXYZ","_id.c":"12345","_id.d":"FG","_id.e": new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")},
                        {"try.Ind":"A","_id.a":"AB","_id.b":"BBBT","_id.c":"23457","_id.d":"DA","_id.e":new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}


                    ]
                }]
               }
            },
            {$project:
                {
                  "try": 1,
                    total:{
                      $sum:{
                        $let: {
                          vars: {
                              array:{
                                    $filter:{
                          input:"$try",
                          cond:{$and:[{$eq:["$$this.Ind","A"]},{$gt:["$$this.mt",0.0]}]}
                    }
                }},
                        "in":"$$array.mt"

                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
    ])
```

MyCollection Data:

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "a" : "NA",
        "b" : "HXYZ",
        "c" : "12345",
        "d" : "CA",
        "e" : "2018-03-09",
    },
    "try" : [ 
        {
            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 2.0,

        }, 
        {
            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 3.0,

        }, 
        {
            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 4.0,

        }, 
        {
            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 5.0,

        }, 
        {
            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 6.0,

        }, 
        {
            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 7.0,

        }
    ]
}

/* 2*/
{
    "_id" : {
        "a" : "AA",
        "b" : "ACDE",
        "c" : "45678",
        "d" : "AB",
        "e" : "2018-03-09",
    },
    "try" : [ 
        {

            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 2.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 3.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 4.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 5.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 6.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 7.0,

        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "a" : "BB",
        "b" : "BBBY",
        "c" : "89012",
        "d" : "BA",
        "e" : "2004-02-12",
    },
    "try" : [ 
        {

            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 2.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 3.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 4.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 5.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "A",
            "mt" : 6.0,

        }, 
        {

            "Ind" : "B",
            "mt" : 7.0,

        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output:

if Ind="A" and mt>0.0

for account 12345,

2.0+4.0+6.0=12

for account 89012,

2.0+4.0+6.0=12

and so on...

output will be something lyk below,

```
{
    {
            "_id": {
            "a" : "NA",
            "b" : "HXYZ",
            "c" : "12345",
            "d" : "CA",
            "e" : "2018-03-09",
            },
            "total": 12
    },{     "_id": {
                "a" : "BB",
                "b" : "BBBY",
                "c" : "89012",
                "d" : "BA",
                "e" : "2004-02-12",
            },
            "total" :12

    }
}
```

Please correct me if the above query works for multiple accounts and get the sum for all accounts in one go from the collection?

I also need corresponding java code using aggregates for the above query especially the match criteria.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your query is correct!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoDb $in with aggregate query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034143/mongodb-in-with-aggregate-query)